# How hide rotate device orientation changes on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How hide rotate device orientation changes on flutter?

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
           DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
           DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]);
        return MaterialApp(...);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Use this inside main() of main.dart

//make sure that you have an instance of the WidgetsBinding.
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
   [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
  ); // To set your device orientation throughout the App.
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?